# What's the name for the [0,1] equivalent of rank or percentile?

Tags: terminology, quantiles, ranks

I am visualizing some distributions by plotting sorted collections of values, effectively the inverse of a cumulative distribution.  The X-axis would thus be the rank.  Since the sizes of my collections are different, however, I've normalized rank to put everything on a 0 to 1 range.  Example of one of my plots:
[image: example plot]

Currently, I have the wrong label, "percentile", on these axes---wrong because I'm normalized to [0,1] and not [0,100].

What is the right label for the X axis?  I feel like there's something like "percentile" that's better and more specific than "normalized rank", but both my memory and my Google-fu are failing me.

Comment: Percentiles are not necessarily "per cent"s, to anyone who's looking at a QQ-plot (or whatever you have here), you can assume they can see percentiles ranging from 0 to 1 and get what you mean.

Comment: @AdamO Sure, somebody can figure out what I mean from context, but I'd rather use the right term if I can figure out what it is.  Or if "percentile" has a second usage meaning a [0,1] range, do you have a reference that shows that term is appropriate?

Comment: maybe quantile?

Comment: This appears to be an 'empirical' CDF (ECDF) plot. It is constructed by sorting a sample of size $n$ from smallest to largest for the x-axis and making a jump function that increases by $1/n$ at each sorted data value (multiple jumps of $k/n$ in case of $k$ observations tied at at point.)

Comment: @BruceET An empirical CDF would typically have the X and Y axes switched from mine, and would label the [0,1] axis "probability."  That doesn't seem appropriate to me here, however.

Comment: Yes, maybe yours is a quantile-quantile plot. But they can be of two varieties--one with data quantiles of the vertical axis and one with them on the horizontal axis. I don't recall seeing anything labeled in _exactly_ the same way as the plot you show. // I tried to post a modification of my first comment, but it may have crossed paths with your response.

Comment: One could characterize this graphic as a kind of "uniform Q-Q plot."  ("Kind of" means the choice of plotting points as $0/(n-1),1/(n-1),\ldots, (n-1)/(n-1)$ instead of, say, $(1/2)/n, (3/2)/n, \ldots, (n-1/2)/n$ is a little unusual, but there's nothing wrong with it.)

Comment: I'm not asking for the name of the graph, I'm asking for a better label for the X axis.

Comment: When you conceive of this as a cumulative *probability* distribution, then a good label for the x-axis is "probability." Otherwise it could be [relative] "frequency," "proportion below," or some such synonym.